# Secure Image is being called Insecure?

Tags: images, https

I have an image using the secure protocol (https://) but the image is being called insecurely from our homepage using the protocol (http://) - How is this possible? Our SSL Certificate is installed correctly & our Secure Padlock Icon will not show because of this. Thank you!

(Secure) As found in the source code: https://shopcandelabra.com/skin/frontend/default/candelabra/images/virtualtour.jpg

(Insecure) What the homepage is calling: http://shopcandelabra.com/skin/frontend/default/candelabra/images/virtualtour.jpg

Comment: Please edit your question  to include the HTML code that loads this image.

Comment: Is magento897.com your real domain name?  It doesn't appear to be registered or have DNS associated with it.  Whois: `No match for "MAGENTO897.COM".`  ping: `ping: unknown host magento897.com.`

Comment: You may want to double-check the link to the image for HTTPS. This seems to be the primary reason I see for your issue. We have all made this mistake! If your link is correct, please let us know so that we can give a better answer.

Comment: I corrected the link as requested & seriously appreciate everyone's help & patience. I confirmed that the link is correct but it's not being called correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**301 Redirect**

Appears your image file has a 301 redirect.  So the browser will load the `HTTP` version while the code says `HTTPS`.

```
curl -I https://www.shopcandelabra.com/skin/frontend/default/candelabra/images/virtualtour.jpg
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 09 Jul 2014 16:12:53 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Location: http://shopcandelabra.com/skin/frontend/default/candelabra/images/virtualtour.jpg
Vary: User-Agent
```

You will want to inspect any rewrite rules that could be triggering this.

Comment: Well spotted! The same with `bottom-artswinner.jpg`. Interesting that a direct request for these images doesn't trigger the redirect - maybe the OP is checking the referer?!

Comment: Fixed it thanks to you guys!! The re-direct was only working selectively?? Have you ever heard of such a thing??? Weird, but then again my knowledge is limited. I just changed the URL for those images in question or in this case from https://(www) to https://(non-www) to avoid the re-direct & it solved the issue. Now our PadLock Icon is showing on Secure Pages!! Perhaps I can return the favor one day! Take Care.

Comment: You likely have a canonical URL rule somewhere that may be trapping all `HTTP_HOST` and rewriting it to `http`.  If you have both `http` and `https` then you will want to add a `SERVER_PORT` rule into your rewrite to selectively redirect `http` and `https`.